# Couldn't load Cookies file generated from firebug into Apache jMeter Cookie management?

Tags: jmeter

I am testing my website which requiring cookies data be set properly, and there is quite a lot cookies data making it annoying to add it manually. I google a little and know that I might export cookies out of Firefox firebug and load it in jMeter HTTP COOKIES MANAGER. However I try many times and fail to see any cookie data imported, there is just nothing changed, I don't know what's going on.

I am using the latest jMeter. Any suggestions?

These are some of my cookie data, exported out of firebug

```
.qq.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1755394742  RK  xGvq1yp4Tf
.tenpay.com TRUE    /   FALSE   certallnum  1
.tenpay.com TRUE    /   FALSE   certinfo    1|150537011-
.tenpay.com TRUE    /   FALSE   certlist    150537011-
.tenpay.com TRUE    /   FALSE   certuserflag    1
.tenpay.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1441074265  ctrlServErr undefined
.qq.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1443526587  lskey   0001000064e173918a7f1bfc52dc25d64a62e88892dfc1128b742e69cdf304aecaf2136b14628f2188588a3a
.qq.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1443526587  luin    o0414077270
.qq.com TRUE    /   FALSE   2147385600  o_cookie    414077270
```

And this how I tried to load those cookie data:
[image]

Comment: can you show some screenshot of cookies content and explain how you're proceeding to import ? thx

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's HTTP Cookie Manager is smart enough to handle cookies on its own.

Looking into response from `tenpay.com` website I can see the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="GB2312">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://www.tenpay.com/v2/">
    <title>²Æ¸¶Í¨ - »áÖ§¸¶ »áÉú»î</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Pay attention to that line:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://www.tenpay.com/v2/">
```

As per [User Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

> JMeter is not a browser. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever viewed at a time).

It means that JMeter won't open `https://www.tenpay.com/v2/` URL automatically, you'll need to explicitly "tell" JMeter to execute GET request to that URL.

1. Extract URL from the `<meta http-equiv="refresh"...` bit with the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743642-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jmeter) like:

   - Add Regular Expression Extractor as a child of the first request
   - Configure it as follows:

     - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `URL`
     - Regular Expression: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=(.+?)">`
     - Template: `$1$`
2. Add a new HTTP Request sampler after 1st sampler, leave everything intact and put `${URL}` in "Path" input so your test plan would look something like:

   [image: Test Plan Example]

Comment: well, I have found out the problem lie in that cookies format exported from firebug might sometimes be unusable because of the format. I looked into the source code of jMeter, and realize that. jMeter doesn't tell us what the problem is when the format is illegal.